# Excel crashes during Excel.run - OfficeJS

Tags: office-js

My Excel crashes any time a function with `Excel.run(function (ctx) {...` is run. I've done quite a bit of testing and `Excel.run` always seems to trigger the crash. The add-in works on other computers, but not mine. I am on the latest version of Windows 10, latest version of Excel, have un-install / re-installed Office. Some other third-party add-ins seem to crash Excel as well. Is there a known bug that would be causing this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is there anything in the event log? What is the version and build number of Excel you're using?

Comment: I was just getting "Excel is not responding" and it would eventually crash. This was Excel Version 1707 (Build 8326.2107 Click-to-Run). I just updated to Version 1708 (Build 8431.2079 Click-to-Run) and the issue is gone. I assume something was resolved between versions.

Comment: Probably it looks like the operation that you are doing inside excel run is causing the error. Can you share the code that you have written inside excel run?